# Blocking unsubscribe spam

Tags: linux, email, email-server, spam, spam-filter

I have SpamAssassin turned on and using RBL in the WHM control panel using the lists from spamhaus. However, these type of e-mails are getting in. Are there any ways to stop them?

Example of the e-mails I have been getting:
http://i48.tinypic.com/i6j8jr.png

Would it be possible to use SpamAssassin to block links with the word unsubscribe in them?

EDIT: Are there any custom and more advanced SpamAssassin rulesets that can be downloaded and used?

Comment: Sure, if you want a billion false positives for legitimate e-mails...

Comment: What are other ideas then?

Comment: Tiffany I think you need to re-think the way you approach spam filtering. Try lowering the spam score on Spam Assassin and let the Bayes filter do their thing.

Comment: Bayes? Right now it is at 5. Should I make it 1?

Comment: You should try and find a setting that works for you.

Comment: Making huge, unpremeditated adjustments to the spam threshold score will have huge unintended consequences. Look at the `X-Spam-Status` header line for these messages that you're receiving. If they're scoring 4.5, then maybe it makes sense to change the threshold to 4. You want to act on *data* specific to your own situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can [customize SpamAssassin's rules](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WritingRules) to do whatever you want. All you need to do is edit your `local.cf` file. However, you will want to think carefully before setting up a custom rule that would condemn any inbound message on the basis of a single rule match (like the word "unsubscribe"). For obvious reasons, this is guaranteed to create false positives.

How are the spam messages that you are receiving being scored, according to the `X-Spam-Status` header line? Are they already close to the spam threshold? Perhaps all you need to do is make a minor adjustment.

Useful documentation:

- [How to Improve SpamAssassin Accuracy](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/ImproveAccuracy)
- [Writing and Testing New SpamAssassin Rules](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WritingRules)
- [How do I add custom SpamAssassin rules for content filtering?](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_add_custom_spamassassin_rules_for_content_filtering.html)